# Netbeans - tabs are not typed in empty lines

Tags: netbeans

Tab key doesn't work in empty lines in Netbeans. If I type something(e.g. a dot), then it works.

How to enable tab key in empty lines?

Comment: Tabs work fine in empty lines for me. It must have something to do with the particular file or project you are working on or some setting you changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make sure you have the [latest JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/) installed and used by Netbeans.
 Currently 17.0.1 (01.2022).**

I was using Netbeans 12.6 with jdk 1.8.0_261. When pressing TAB on an empty line nothing happened but in the bottom right corner you can see a notification that a unexpected MethodNotFound Exception is thrown. Installing JDK 17.0.1 fixed it. Make sure your IDE actually uses the new JDK by going to 
`Tools -> Java Platforms` and the JDK 17 is the default one.

Comment: This is one solution, but it is not the only one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70702558/2985643) for alternative approaches, and an explanation for why this issue arises.